# How can I make that my program does not crash?

Tags: assembly, fasm

I don't understand why Windows can't run this program without it crashing, moreover, the "shield" icon (administrator mode) is inserted on the executable program icon. Here is my code (FASM assembler, x86-64):

```
format PE
entry main

foo:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        enter 3, 0
        mov BYTE [ebp-1], al
        mov DWORD [ebp-8], edi
        mov DWORD [ebp-12], esi
        pop ebp
        leave
        ret
main:
        mov ebp, esp
        mov DWORD [ebp-4], edi
        mov DWORD [ebp-16], esi
        mov al, 97
        mov edi, 43
        mov esi, 76
        call foo
        pop ebp
        ret
```

The code seems correct to me, I don't think that's the problem, maybe some missing instructions? I don't know...

PS: Strange effect: when I change the directory of the program (which is by default on the desktop), the shield disappears... I don't really understand...

Note: Maybe to you it's obvious, but to me it's not. And my Internet searches found nothing conclusive.

[Code Edit 1]:

Example of another program, even more simplified, which crashes for no apparent reason:

```
format PE console

org 100h

mov ah,09
mov dx,msg
int 21h
mov ah,08
int 21h
int 20h
msg db "hello world!$"
```

[Edit code 2]:

```
format PE
entry main

main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov DWORD [ebp-4], edi
        mov DWORD [ebp-16], esi
        mov edi, 8
        call square
        pop ebp
        ret
square:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov DWORD [ebp-4], edi
        pop ebp
        ret
```

Comment: At a guess: you are interleaving `leave` and `pop`.  I'm guessing this mucks up the stack such that the `ret` fails.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: I had also thought about it, but it turns out that even a program even simpler than this one crash also, without even using leave, or enter.

Comment: Post the simpler code. This one also happens to use memory under the stack pointer which is a possible cause for crashing. Also, if you are really in 64 bit mode, using 32 bit pointers is not the best idea. I don't know where windows places the stack though.

Comment: @Jester: Here, I edited the question to make another program appear, which does not use pop/push/leave/ret/enter, but still crashes. Is it possible that this is related to the `format PE console` ?

Comment: This one is using old DOS interrupts and is 16 bit code. No wonder this crashes.

Comment: @Jester: Yes, indeed (excuse me for the bad example), but what about the 1st code then? It doesn't use DOS interrupt, yet it crashes. When I incorporate `mscvrt` into the code, and use `ExitProcess` (no example needed I think), there is no more problem. But I would like to realise it without this libraries.

Comment: The first one crashes because you messed up the `enter`/`leave` nesting so the return address is probably corrupted hence `ret` blows up. `ExitProcess` still works because that doesn't need a valid return address.

Comment: @Jester: I created a new code (see edit 2), it doesn't crash anymore, but seems to make an infinite loop (the program doesn't close). What's the problem now?

Comment: Accessing under the stack pointer is still a bad idea. Apart from that, this looks like it should work, and indeed it does here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are trying to set stack frame in two different independent ways - by `enter/leave` and by `push/pop`. And as a result you are simply messing the stack, so the program returns on a wrong address on the `ret` instruction.

Use only one of these methods and don't forget about setting the exit code:

### Variant 1

```
format PE
entry main

foo:
        enter 12, 0
        mov  BYTE [ebp-1], al
        mov  DWORD [ebp-8], edi
        mov  DWORD [ebp-12], esi
        leave
        ret
main:
        enter 16, 0
        mov  DWORD [ebp-4], edi
        mov  DWORD [ebp-16], esi
        mov  al, 97
        mov  edi, 43
        mov  esi, 76
        call foo
        leave
        xor  eax, eax    ; exit code
        ret
```

### Variant 2

```
format PE
entry main

foo:
        push ebp
        mov  ebp, esp
        sub  esp, 12
        mov  BYTE [ebp-1], al
        mov  DWORD [ebp-8], edi
        mov  DWORD [ebp-12], esi
        mov  esp, ebp
        pop  ebp
        ret
main:
        push ebp
        mov  ebp, esp
        sub  esp, 16
        mov  DWORD [ebp-4], edi
        mov  DWORD [ebp-16], esi
        mov  al, 97
        mov  edi, 43
        mov  esi, 76
        call foo
        mov  esp, ebp
        pop  ebp
        xor  eax, eax    ; exit code
        ret
```

These both variants will not crash and will terminate properly, although they do nothing useful actually. What actually you are trying to achieve?

P.S. Your dos example also works, but you need to compile it with a little bit different options:

```
format binary as "com"

org 100h

mov ah,09
mov dx,msg
int 21h
mov ah,08
int 21h
int 20h
msg db "hello world!$"
```

Now compile and run the result `.com` file in DOS or using DosBox in Windows or Linux:

```
$dosbox myprog.com
```

Comment: The problem isn't mixing teardown methods, it's doing it twice.  You can use `leave` to tear down a stack frame created by  `push ebp` / `mov ebp, esp`.  That's what gcc does, if ESP isn't already pointing to the saved EBP value.  (`enter` is slow, but `leave` is only 1 extra uop vs. `mov`/`pop`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Even creating stack frame twice, it would not cause crash if it was nested properly. But actually, the OP does not understand fully how the stack works and why at all we need to create stack frames.

Comment: I think last time I looked, I missed that the OP had `enter` in one of the versions.  But yeah, looks like a total lack of understanding to use parts of it like that.  Still, I'd be happier if your answer suggested ignoring `enter` entirely, and always used `push`/`mov` (with an optional `sub esp` or a `push` ) to create stack frames.  `enter` might be useful if you needed a stack frame in code-golf, but I don't think "high-level" instructions like `loop`, `enter` or `leave` are helpful for beginner to learn about the stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes Exactly because push/mov variant is more clear I added it to the answer. But omitting features only because they are more complex, is wrong IMO. At least OP already know something about enter/leave. Also notice that this example is actually very stupid, because it does not need any stack frames at all. I wasn't even able to say what the OP wanted this code to do. My goal was only to show how the code can be made to terminate properly.

Comment: I'm saying if I was teaching a class for beginners, I wouldn't mention `loop` or `enter`.  The ISA ref manual is there for anyone that wants to go digging and find them, or other complex stuff like `rep movsb`, `shld`, `pusha`, `xlat` or whatever other instructions they don't need right away (or ever for some of those) .  But you're right that if they're already asking about enter/leave you shouldn't leave it out of the answer.